# QTcpSocket бьются данные

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Пишу прототип клиент-серверного приложения, в боевом режиме приложение должно передавать ~200 значений вида QString, QVariant около 60 раз в секунду.

Проблема в том, что при таком темпе отправки на клиенте я успешно получаю примерно один пак данных из 50, в остальных случаях взятые из потока переменные оказываются инвалидными (`QVariant::invalid`)

Код для сервера:

```
void TDummyWorker::initialize()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(10); 
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(foo()));   //будем посылать данные с заданным интервалом
    timer->start();
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server,&QTcpServer::newConnection,this,&TDummyWorker::somebodyConnected);
    server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 33333);
}

void TDummyWorker::foo()
{
    QVector <TNamedVariable> vars;
    static int n=0;
    int ndata = 200;
    for (int i=0; i<ndata; i++)
    {
        //формируем фейковые данные
        vars.append(TNamedVariable("variable_number_" % QString::number(i), (i%2 != 0 ? float((i+n)*0.01) : int(i+n)) ));
    }
    for (QMap<int ,QTcpSocket *>::iterator it = clients.begin(); it!=clients.end(); ++it)
    {
        sendToClient(*it, vars);  //посылаем данные всем подключенным клиентам
    }
    n++;
    if (n>1000000) n=0;
}

void TDummyWorker::sendToClient(QTcpSocket *socket, QVector <TNamedVariable> &vars)
{
    QByteArray arr;
    QDataStream out(&arr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);
    int n=vars.size();
    out << quint16(0);
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        out << vars[i];
    }
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << quint16(arr.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    sendMessage(vars[0].value.toString() % " " % QString::number(arr.size() - sizeof(quint16)));
    socket->write(arr);
}
```

А вот так получаю данные на стороне клиента:

```
void TClient::recieveData()
{
    QDataStream stream(socket);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);
    QVector <TNamedVariable> vars;
    quint16 nextBlockSize=0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (nextBlockSize==0)
        {
            if (socket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) 
            {
                break;
            }
            stream >> nextBlockSize;
        }
        if (socket->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize) 
            break;
        TNamedVariable buf;
        while (!stream.atEnd())
        {
            stream >> buf;
            buf.debug();
            vars.append(buf);
        }

        nextBlockSize = 0;
    }
    emit sendData(vars);
}
```

Если же отправлять по 1-2 переменных раз в секунду, то на стороне клиента все принимается нормально, чем больше я увеличиваю частоту передачи и количество переменных в векторе, тем больше битых данных я получаю.
Подозреваю, что ошибка достаточно тривиальна, потому что код почти полностью из примеров из учебника.

Корректно работающий код после всех правок:

```
void TClient::recieveData()
{
    QDataStream stream(socket);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);
    static int nbad = 0;
    TNamedVariable buf;
    static quint16 nextBlockSize=0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (nextBlockSize == 0)
        {
            if (socket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16))
            {
                break;
            }
            stream >> nextBlockSize;
        }
        if (socket->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize)
        {
            break;
        }
        while (!stream.atEnd())
        {
            stream >> buf;
            if (!buf.value.isValid())
            {
                qDebug()<<"op :("<<++nbad;
            }
            if (buf.name == "eod")
                break;
            vars.append(buf);
        }
        if (buf.name == "eod")
        {
            emit sendData(vars);
            vars.clear();
        }
        nextBlockSize = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в `nextBlockSize`, а точнее в том, что переменная существует локально, не сохраняя своё значение между вызовами `recieveData()`.

При получении сетевой пакет может содержать значение для `nextBlockSize`, а также какую-то часть данных из тела сообщения. Тогда блок кода, где проверяется `nextBlockSize`, отработает корректно, а вот условие:

```
if (socket->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize) break;
```

... приведёт контекст выполнения к выходу из метода. Тогда `nextBlockSize` потеряет своё значение и новый вызов `recieveData()` со вновь закаченными данными не отработает корректно, т.к. размер сообщения из потока уже был ранее прочитан.

**Дополнение**

Ещё одна проблема может возникнуть в цикле `while (!stream.atEnd()) {}` в методе `recieveData()`. Полученное сообщение, помимо своего содержимого, может содержать и часть данных следующего сообщения. Обозначенный цикл в этом случае отработает некорректно.

```
void SocketManager::onReadyRead() {
    QTcpSocket *socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    if(socket == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    QDataStream stream(socket);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    forever {
        quint32 receive_data_size
            = socket->property("receive-data-size").toUInt();

        if(receive_data_size == 0) {
            if(socket->bytesAvailable() < (qint64)sizeof(quint32))
                return;

            stream >> receive_data_size;

            socket->setProperty("receive-data-size", receive_data_size);
        }

        if(socket->bytesAvailable() < receive_data_size) return;

        socket->setProperty("receive-data-size", 0);

        QVariant var;
        stream >> var;

        emit dataReceived(var);
    }
}
```

В представленном примере имеется только один цикл `forever`, который задействует повторную итерацию с самого начала (включая проверку на получение размера сообщения) сразу после того, как будут прочитаны данные текущего сообщения.

`receive_data_size` - это размер сообщения. В примере оно сохраняется в свойствах объекта сокета. Это удобно в том случае, если один и тот же слот приёма данных вызывается несколькими сокетами.

Comment: Объявил nextBlockSize как static, стало лучше, но все равно под нагрузкой в четверть от "боевой" из 15 передач 5 неудачные. Загрузка сети, если верить диспетчеру задач windows 1%

Comment: У Вас в примере кода в двух строках вызывается `break`, приводящий к выходу из цикла `while`. Сразу за этим следует отправка сигнала `sendData()` даже если данные и не были получены полностью. Нужно добавить какую-нибудь обработку для этого исключения.

Comment: Получилось, но не до конца:  иногда все же проскакивают битые переменные, и размер прилетевшего массива иногда получается вдвое больше, чем должен быть. Немного не понимаю Ваш пример - у Вас отправляется одна прилетевшая переменная, а мне бы собрать массив и отправить его целиком.

Comment: У меня просто пример. Если Вы хотите отправлять `TNamedVariable` не по одному, а сразу массивом, то предварительно вставляйте в поток кол-во элементов этого самого массива. Ориентироваться на "eod", наверное, не вполне правильно.

Comment: Ещё вариантом может быть отправка непосредственно всего `QVector<TNamedVariable>` как он есть. Правда для этого Вам придётся зарегистрировать этот тип данных в метаобъектной системе Qt.

Comment: Разобрался с проблемой, все дело было в этом: "Полученное сообщение, помимо своего содержимого, может содержать и часть данных следующего сообщения". Перенес проверку if (buf.name == "eod") и все заработало как нужно.