# QTcpSocket отказоустойчивость при передаче сложных объектов

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket

Работаю над программой с передачей данных по сети, передаются объекты типа `QVariant` или пары объектов `QString, QVariant`. Прототипы работают нормально (тут есть код приема и передачи для наглядности - [QTcpSocket бьются данные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552419/qtcpsocket-%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)). Прием идет стабильно, но код приема основывается на непрерывности корректного потока данных. Если же в сети случаются проблемы, например, выпадения пакетов, прием ломается, так как нарушается ожидаемая очередность передачи, и восстановить связь без переподключения невозможно. Вопрос - какие механизмы использовать для обеспечния отказоустойчивости, как найти новое начало блока полезных данных при пропадении связи и есть ли какие-то best practices в этой области, применительно в `QTcpSocket`?

Сетевые проблемы эмулирую с помощью программы Climsy

Прототип серверной программы: https://github.com/BeardedBeaver/ServerPrototype

Прототип клиентской программы: https://github.com/BeardedBeaver/ClientPrototype

Comment: TCP протокол так устроен, что очередность байт гарантирована. Если какой то пакет "выпал", он будет перепослан. В современных системах практечески не бывает такого, что в tcp нарушается последовательность пакетов (я такого не видел). 
Во времена более древние, когда токое было возможно (а также на более низких укровнях), применяют "самосинхронизиующиеся последовательности". Классический пример - utf-8.

Comment: @KoVadim в теории да, но на практике это происходит не всегда, и при наличии сетевых помех передача нарушается. В стабильной локальной сети все происходит корректно. Так что вопрос открыт. На счет самосинхронизирующихся последовательностей спасибо, почитаю подробнее, выглядит как что-то, похожее на решение

Comment: Если портятся байты и пересылка не помогает, TCP разорвет подключение. Так что вопрос закрыт:).

Comment: @KoVadim мне выложить исполняемые файлы прототипа и его код, на примере которых видно, что это не так? Вопрос я задаю не на пустом месте и не в теории, а после некоторого времени, проведенного в практических исследованиях.

Comment: Исполняемые файлы ненужны. Они ведь скрывают ошибки. Лушче показывать код, который собственно читает/пишет из/в сокета. А ещё лушче - минимальный пример, который воспроизводит ситуацию.

Comment: @KoVadim добавил ссылки на github

Comment: в коде чтения с сокета есть код `while (true)
    {

    }`

это пять! (а второй репозиторий совсем пустой).

Comment: @KoVadim исправил код во втором репозитории. `while (true) { }` это заготовка для кода чтения, который никогда не используется, клиент ничего не передает на сервер в этом прототипе. Запушил изменение, в котором закомментарил этот кусок, чтобы он не смущал

Comment: Код конечно страшненький, но более-менее рабочий до тех пор, пока блок данных не станет больше 64*1024 байт.

Answer (score 3):

В Qt версии 5.7 появился такой интересный инструментарий, как транзакционное чтение. Помимо заявленной проверки целостности серии данных, отправленных посредством череды операторов записи в поток `QDataStream`, этот механизм также осуществляет и проверку на соответствие типа и размера каждой из полученных позиций.

Таким образом, целостность данных (серии данных) может контролироваться простым образом:

```
void SocketManager::socketSendMessage(const QVariant &var) {
    QByteArray data;

    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    stream << var;

    _socket->write(data);
}

void SocketManager::onSocketReceiveMessage() {
    QDataStream stream(_socket);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    while(_socket->bytesAvailable()) {
        stream.startTransaction();

        QVariant var;
        stream >> var;

        if(stream.commitTransaction() == false) return;

        // Работаем с данными...
    }
}
```

Если данные были получены не полностью или не соответствуют ожиданию (в примере это тип `QVariant`), то транзакция завершена не будет. В этом случае реакция может быть различной и зависит от фантазии автора кода. Можно подождать ещё некоторое время до подхода отставшего куска. Можно инкрементировать счётчик безуспешных попыток, и уже опираясь на его значение предпринять некие шаги.

Если нет уверенности, что этого достаточно, можно воспользоваться дополнительным механизмом, который, хотя и не предназначен для проверки корректности данных, может таковым стать. Например, это может быть обычная декомпрессия из архива:

```
QByteArray SocketManager::compressData(const QVariant &var) {
    QByteArray data;

    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);
    stream << var;

    return qCompress(data, 9);
}

QVariant SocketManager::uncompressData(const QByteArray &data) {
    QByteArray raw_data = qUncompress(data);
    if(raw_data.isEmpty()) return QVariant();

    QDataStream stream(raw_data);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    QVariant var;
    stream >> var;

    return var;
}
```

Ну и конечно остаётся немного подправить код отправки и получения:

```
void SocketManager::socketSendMessage(const QVariant &var) {
    QByteArray data;

    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    stream << compressData(var);

    _socket->write(data);
}

void SocketManager::onSocketReceiveMessage() {
    QDataStream stream(_socket);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    while(_socket->bytesAvailable()) {
        stream.startTransaction();

        QByteArray data;
        stream >> data;

        // Если не докачалось, то ждём новую порцию данных.
        if(data.isEmpty() == true) {
            // QByteArray подвержен сериализации также,
            // как и другие контейнеры со вставкой размера
            // перед началом данных, поэтому если по факту
            // данных будет меньше, нежели чем было записано,
            // то буфер окажется пустой.
            stream.rollbackTransaction();
            return;
        }

        // Целостность (соответствие размеру) проверили,
        // теперь пытаемся проверить корректность.
        QVariant var = uncompressData(data);

        // Порядок.
        if(var.isValid() == true) {
            // Поскольку "commit" в случае неуспеха
            // сделает "rollback" и возвратит позицию
            // чтения на начало транзакции, то в ситуации
            // с необходимостью отбрасывания повреждённых
            // данных расположение "commit" до проверки их
            // корректности не имеет смысла.
            if(stream.commitTransaction() == false) {
                // Этот исход вряд ли возможен
                // после всех проверок.
            }
        }

        // Возникли проблемы с корректностью данных.
        else {
            // "abort" вызовет "commit" со сдвигом
            // позиции на место, находящееся после
            // повреждённых данных.
            stream.abortTransaction();
        }

        // Работаем с данными...
    }
}
```

Помимо того, что размер пересылаемой информации может быть уменьшен в несколько раз, в случае повреждения данных снижается вероятность, что распаковка произойдёт успешно.

**Дополнение**

Если рассматривать операции с транзакциями без учёта вложенности (это тоже поддерживается), то каждая из них сводится к следующему:

- `startTransaction()` - запоминает текущую позицию чтения в буфере;
- `commitTransaction()` - удаляет данные в буфере при этом обнуляя
  позицию чтения;
- `rollbackTransaction()` - возвращает позицию чтения, не
  затрагивая данных;
- `abortTransaction()` - фактически тоже, что и `commitTransaction()`, но установит статус `QDataStream::ReadCorruptData`.

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит интересно. В моем (боевом) коде уже используется qCompress для снижения объема передаваемых данных, так что отследить некорректную передачу достаточно просто. Изучу механизм транзакций. Я, возможно, не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос - меня интересует, как быть в случае, когда я уже зафиксировал некорректную передачу, то есть что-то по дороге побилось и мне надо пропустить побитый кусок, найти новое начало данных и продолжить чтение из потока в штатном режиме.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, Вам должны помочь вот эти транзакции, которые я описал в ответе. У `QDataStream` есть также метод `abortTransaction()`, который можно использовать в том случае, если получение данных не прошло успешно и при этом требуется не ждать подхода неуспевших придти данных из того же блока, а обрубить появившиеся "хвосты" (включая зачистку буфера сокета).

Comment: Ага... а как быть если при этом в сокете также лежит начало нового блока данных? Рубить и чистить пока не повезет и новая порция данных не будет начинаться с начала блока? Или я не так понимаю принцип работы сокета?

Comment: При `abortTransaction()` можно продолжать читать стрим (буфер) далее, как если бы это был новый блок. Надо немного изменить ответ для такого варианта.

Comment: > то есть что-то по дороге побилось и мне надо пропустить побитый кусок, найти новое начало данных и продолжить чтение из потока в штатном режиме.

В этом случае Вы выиграли джек пот. 

>  Или я не так понимаю принцип работы сокета? 
да, Вы похоже его сильно не понимаете.

Comment: @KoVadim, сам я никогда не получал такой ситуации, но чисто теоретически такое возможно, чтобы отправляемый блок оказался меньшего размера на приёмной стороне по причине именно выпадения части данных, скажем, по середине блока?

Comment: "выпасть" данные не могут. Все пакеты занумерованы и имеют crc. Да, мне известно, что в больших датацентрах вроде как были ситуации, когда пакет был не тот, а crc совпала.
Но с tcp бывает другая ситуация (и это нормально) - когда с одной стороны отправляется скажем 10 и еще 20 байт, а на приемной приходит 5, 10 и 15. (то есть, ушло два, а пришло три). Но порядок байт будет правильным (да, на таких мелких размерах это не воспроизводиться, а вот на 1000-2000 байтах уже можно и словить).

Comment: @KoVadim, "... на 1000-2000 байтах уже можно и словить" - это в смысле то, что блок будет возможно поделен на несколько составляющих частей на входе у приёмной стороны или Вы о другом?

Comment: О том, что блок может быть поделен. В целом, тут все зависит от сети. Если на localhost'е пробовать, тот тут нужно сильно постараться и обычно, если отправлено 3000-4000 байт, ровно сколько же и приходит (и поэтому, тесты на локалхосте такие наивные). Второй этам - это локалка. Тут, если все ок, то пакеты тоже почти всегда приходят такими же. А вот когда выходим в рельный интернет, вот тут вступает MTU и иже с ними и реально начинает дробить после 1500 байт.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, это я понимаю, в моей практике к счастью только дробление всегда имело место быть. Понимать тогда стоит, что пропадание части блока быть не может, но при этом может быть не соответствие реальным данным в отдельных его частях. Тогда я спокоен. Спасибо.